# jQuery change event for non-forms elements

Tags: jquery, events

I'm looking for some kind of `change` event but for non-forms elements.

Problem:
I have a `table` where `tr` tags are changing dynamicly by another script. `Tr` elements are changing from `display:block` to `display:none` or vice versa.

And I need something like this:

event will listing for change of any `tr` in my `table` (not matter to display `none` or `block`) and after any change the script will check if all `tr`s are set as `display:none` and if true then do something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DOM changes like that do not trigger events. Your options are to either update the code that modifies the DOM to also send a custom event, or to poll for changes. The first option is simplest to implement and can look something like this:

```
// Add an event listener for change events
$(document).bind("modified", function() {
    alert("Someone modified " + this);
});

// Modify a table and trigger an event for it
$("#yourTable").css("display", "block").trigger("modified");
```

The poll option will be slower and is not recommended. Minimal example:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var $table = $("#yourTable");
    if ($table.css("display")!="block") {
        alert("The table changed!");
    }
}, 500);
```

this will check your table every 500 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to set a timer to do this. For instance:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var table = $("selector_for_your_table");
    var timerHandle = setInterval(function() {
        if (table.find("tr:visible").length == 0) {
            // No rows in the table are visible, do something
        }
    }, 500);

});
```

That checks once every half-second, which may well be too often. It depends on the size of the table, etc. You'll also want to turn this checking *off* whenever you can to avoid unnecessary work. You can cancel it by calling `cancelInterval(timerHandle);`.

Answer (score 1):

I would create functions for hiding and showing tr elements, and implementing an event firing in it, like calling a tr_was_hidden() or tr_was_shown() function. This way you can handle all the show/hide events as they fire.

```
$.fn.showTR = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).show();
        tr_was_shown();
    });
};

$.fn.hideTR = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        tr_was_hidden();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could use a timer to check periodical whether some content has changed or whether all `tr` elements are set to `display:none`.